# Calculate the number e

Tags: code-golf, number

From Wikipedia:

> The number e is an important mathematical constant that is the base of the natural logarithm. It is approximately equal to 2.71828, and is the limit of (1 + 1/n)n as n approaches infinity.

### Challenge

Calculate the number e to 15 digits after the decimal point.

This means that your output must start with `2.718281828459045` or equivalent.

Your program can output digits after the required output - these may be accurate or inaccurate, inaccuracy after 15 digits does not disqualify you from the challenge. Your program may also output nothing after the required 15 digits.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest implementation in bytes wins.

### Constraints

- You may not use built in constants or hardcode the number.
- Standard loopholes and rules apply.

### Reference Implementation (Ruby)

```
def e(i) 
  e = 1.0                        # make it floating point
  i.times { |n|                  # loop repeats n times
    e += 1.0/(1..n+1).reduce(:*) # factorial - no factorial function
  }                              # in the Ruby standard library
  return e
end
e(200)                           # Almost certainly will return e
```

Comment: Uh, the built in constant part is a bit unclear, what if I do `exp(1)`? What about `(-1)^(1/i*pi))`?

Comment: You mention the lim, but then your reference uses the series sum...

Comment: Sorry, a search didn't find the previous question.

Comment: @Adám The quote is copy pasted from Wikipedia. The article also shows the series sum formula.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Use your common sense. Please don't try getting around the rules.

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell, <s>33</s> 31 Bytes

*-2 Bytes thanks to @xnor*

```
sum[1/product[1..i]|i<-[0..99]]
```

Straightforward implementation of the series definition. (I have posted a version of this to Reddit before.)

Comment: You don't need parens around the product.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 25 bytes

```haskell
f 99=0;f n=1+f(n+1)/n;f 0
```

26 bytes:

```haskell
foldr(\x y->1+y/x)0[1..99]
```